# Extract image from .MHT file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mhtml

I want to extract an image from MHT file. Tried using https://github.com/zsxsoft-deprecated/mhtml-parser, but it does not seem to working.

For the sample MHT as well it is just throwing following error

```
Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ('Unsupported version')
```